# gcsfuse automount on a non root user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mount, fstab, gcloud, gcsfuse

Currently I have a VM that runs `CentOS 7` and would like to auto mount a bucket using a non root user.

I have installed NextCloud and would like to point local data folder to `Google Cloud Storage`.

Tried various examples but none of them seemed to work, at all.

Here's what I've tried:

The mount works but not the creation of any file / folder as a sub folder or file placed within the mounted folder

```
gcsfuse my-nextcloud-bucket /mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/public_html/data
```

```
gcsfuse -o nonempty my-nextcloud-bucketcom /mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/public_html/data
```

The following ones I've tried to place each try on `/etc/fstab` (end of file)

```
my-nextcloud-bucket /mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/public_html/data gcsfuse rw,noauto,cloudmysite,key_file=/mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/_gcloud-credentials/gc--1f54d021ca11.json
```

```
my-nextcloud-bucket /mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/public_html/data gcsfuse rw,gid=1068,uid=1065,noauto,user,allow_other,_netdev
```

```
my-nextcloud-bucket /mnt/myserverdata/cloudmysite/public_html/data gcsfuse rw,allow_other,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777
```

How I can mount (fstab or on reboot to be persistent) under `cloudmysite` user which is a non root user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in the docs of [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions).

> You can also mount the file system automatically as a non-root user by specifying the options uid and/or gid:
>
> `my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,_netdev,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1001`

I tested this and the bucket was mounted with my user.